# How to add the ssh key of non-root user during provisioning virtual guest in SoftLayer

Tags: ssh, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to add a normal user(such as 'vcap') ssh key to virtual guest while provisioning because of the security issue.

I just used to add the sshkeys in the virtual guest template as 'SshKeys' property. But it only could work as 'root'. I though the ssh key is given to 'root'. It was not good for me because I disable the root ssh login in the image. Does the SoftLayer support add no-root user sshkey during provisioning?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible, when the provision occurs it will install the Ssh key for the primary user, therefore the "root" user.

For more information please see below:

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faqs/585

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/topic/ssh-keys

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/how-do-i-permit-specific-users-ssh-access

Comment: And one more question. I investigated some methods of operation after virtual guest setup: `provisionScripts`, `Virtual_Guest_SupplementalCreateObjectOptions.PostInstallScriptUri`, `executeRemoteScript`. Do these methods could work on provision finish time? I thought I could use it to set up a normal user ssh key, this user was added to the image building stage. Did you have any suggestion to write post-script. And I wanted to added the script to metadata server.

Comment: And could I prepare a ssh key pair to use in softlayer portal?